# Laptop gets sudden artifact screen and restarts with a strong fan

Tags: windows, crash, overheating

I have a HP probook 5330m. Whenever I run applications like photoshop or play a game, I get this flickering, distorted (green & pink) artifact screen along with a bursting sound, like a tv loosing its signal, followed by a restart. I noticed that the laptop gets very hot before this happens, especially where the left palm rests and that's where the cpu is. This crash doesnt happen if I do less demanding tasks, like browsing, watching movies or doing office work.

Whenever I restart while its's still very hot the crash happens again. The laptop is newly formatted and clean. There are no dust build-ups in the heatsink and the fan works fine. I also have up-to-date display drivers (in some similar cases it's gpu related).

Also:
I directed a small fan at the overheating part, this lessened the heat a lot, but the crash still occurs.

Comment: which part is overheating?

Comment: the whole left side basically, but the left palm rest, beside the touch pad goes intensely hot... i think its where the cpu sits..?

Comment: have you opened the laptop up to see what is actually there?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You say that there is no dust. An often overlooked component is the **thermal paste** between the CPU and the heatsink. The same goes for the GPU. Since your Laptop is rather old, the paste might have dried, which can significantly reduce heat conductivity. Changing the paste might help.

Comment: Yes, if it doesn't crash in "less demanding tasks like browsing", and if fans are clean, then the only issue may be thermal compound.

Comment: thanks for the help.. ill change the paste first and see if it stops these crashes......

Answer (score 2):

Generally when an issue like this starts to happen, there are a couple reasons.
 1. Airflow is highly constricted.
 2. Thermal paste is old and causing the CPU to overwork itself thus start to burn itself out.
 3. CPU or onboard GPU is going bad, or worst case scenario, motherboard is dying.
However, I have seen a case where it was the ram causing issues all along.